# Mostrar só os que não são comuns entre duas querys em mysql

Tags: mysql

Tenho esta primeira query que só mostra os nomes com a data de registo do dia atual:

```
SELECT nome,
       centrodb.registoMiDe.Quarto,
       DataRegisto,
       Miccao,
       Tipo1,
       Dejeccao,
       Tipo

FROM centrodb.utentes LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.registoMiDe

ON centrodb.registoMiDe.NomeUtente = centrodb.utentes.nome

WHERE descricaovalencia = 'LAR' AND nome <> 'CLASSE' AND DAY(DataRegisto) = DAY(CURDATE())
```

Agora na próxima query mostro todos os nome com a data de registo null e dos dias para trás da data atual:

```
SELECT nome,
       centrodb.registoMiDe.Quarto,
       DataRegisto,
       Miccao,
       Tipo1,
       Dejeccao,
       Tipo

FROM centrodb.utentes LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.registoMiDe

ON centrodb.registoMiDe.NomeUtente = centrodb.utentes.nome

WHERE descricaovalencia = 'LAR' AND nome <> 'CLASSE' AND DataRegisto IS NULL OR DAY(DataRegisto) < DAY(CURDATE())
```

Agora o objectivo é só mostrar os nomes que não foram ainda registados com a data de registo do dia atual.

Comment: Não entendi bem sua dificuldade... Não seria apenas:   
`DAY(DataRegisto) <> DAY(CURDATE())` ???

Comment: Não e vou passar a explicar, imagine se o mesmo nome existir com o registo da data actual, ele irá aparecer na mesma e o que pretendo  é que se esse nome existir com registo do dia anterior e registo do dia actual não apareça...consegui explicar me?

Comment: Já resolvi a situação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente, basta fazer um `NOT EXISTS` da query que vc não quer que apareça no resultado:

```
    SELECT nome,
           centrodb.registoMiDe.Quarto,
           DataRegisto,
           Miccao,
           Tipo1,
           Dejeccao,
           Tipo

    FROM centrodb.utentes LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.registoMiDe

    ON centrodb.registoMiDe.NomeUtente = centrodb.utentes.nome

    WHERE descricaovalencia = 'LAR' AND nome <> 'CLASSE' AND DataRegisto IS NULL OR DAY(DataRegisto) < DAY(CURDATE()) 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1

                    FROM centrodb.utentes  
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.registoMiDe    
                    ON centrodb.registoMiDe.NomeUtente = centrodb.utentes.nome    
                    WHERE descricaovalencia = 'LAR' 
                    AND nome <> 'CLASSE' 
                    AND DAY(DataRegisto) = DAY(CURDATE()))
```

Comment: Também funciona esta solução, mas utilizei o `NOT IN`

Comment: Legal, realmente o `NOT IN` também funciona, mas de qualquer forma ressalto que o `NOT EXISTS` é mais performático que o `NOT IN`.